# How do I add the function key to a shortcut on fedora

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, fn-key

I already know how to make shortcuts with dconf-editor, but my problem is adding the "fn" key to shortcuts. For example: `fn + f1` to mute audio. Ay help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On most systems, the `fn` key isn't a "real" key, in the sense that it doesn't send values to the OS. Instead, it changes the value of the key that's sent. On my Lenovo laptop (unless FnLock is on), pressing the `F1` key actually sends `Audio Mute` (I think that's [XF86AudioMute](https://docs.rs/xkbcommon/0.2.0/xkbcommon/xkb/keysyms/constant.KEY_XF86AudioMute.html)). If I hold `fn` and press, it sends actual `F1`. (Of course, changing FnLock inverts this.)

Comment: My [keyboard](https://static.cdnlive.com.br/uploads/602/unidade/16240239026978_zoom.jpg) does not have audio specific keys I believe, do you know what could I do?